# Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect my hive version 2.1.0

Tags: hive

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Hadoop/hive/jdbc/hive-jdbc-2.1.0-standalone.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Hadoop/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/System9/Desktop/cloudera/Cloudera_HiveJDBC_2.5.4.1006/Cloudera_HiveJDBC4_2.5.4.1006/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:219)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:157)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:107)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)`enter code here`
    at hive.HiveJdbcClient.main(HiveJdbcClient.java:27)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:226)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:266)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.open(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:195)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:221)
```

how will connect the Hive step by step procedure give me. Explaine hive-site configuration  also i can't set hive username password in hive-site.xml please help me.Thank you